# Magento search result links to product pages use the wrong template

Tags: magento, templates, search, hierarchy

I've modified my search results page to use the 2columns-right template.  But all of my product pages use the 1column template.

When I click on any of the links to products in my Magento search results, the product page is displayed in the left side of the 2columns-right template.  Since product pages should use the 1column template, the result looks broken.

The product pages, when linked to from search results, don't seem to retain their heirarchy in the url, either.  They appear as standalone pages instead of pages within the catalog.  I'm guessing that this is part of the problem.

Is there any way to retain the page heirarchy in search results?  Or any way to get the different types of pages that may show up in search results to use their respective templates?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by editing this block in layout/catalog.xml:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

I just changed the template there & now the results look correct.